# Multiple required conditions of an input with .includes() method

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, input, react-forms

I'm making validation of an email input in my React App, but I want that input should have both `@` and `.(dot)` while submitting the form. I tried the `.some()` method but if only one condition is true then it will return true but I want both:

```
const emailValidation = ["@", "."];
<input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Email"
    value={email}
    onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
    onBlur={(e) => {
        setIsEmailValid(
            emailValidation.some((el) => e.target.value.includes(el))
        );
    }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
     type="text"
     placeholder="Email"
     value={email}
     onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
     onBlur={(e) => {
     setIsEmailValid(
     emailValidation.every((el) => e.target.value.includes(el)));  }}
     />
```

Here you just need to use every() method instead of some()